# Autoclicker in the browser using javascript based on attached css classes

Tags: javascript

For a while now, i want to create an autoclicker for in the browser to click on specific buttons on a website. Since i am pretty familiar with javascript i want to use javascript to write the script. To clarify what i want, imagine a website with a list of items. Each of these items has a button with the content "add" and contains the css class "add-btn". What i want is a script that scans the code of the wanted website and searches for all buttons with the "add-btn" class attached to it. Then i want to trigger the click event for each of these buttons one by one. (If it is possible i want the browser minified and not opened while running the script).

I already did a lot of research on the internet and still haven't found a clear javascript tutorial to achieve my goal. Does anyone maybe have a link to a tutorial that matches my wishes? Or maybe a push in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe i asked the question in a wrong way, my main problem is that i have no idea how to read and "use" the code of an existing website that is not mine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you want is a headless browser, like PhantomJS or Zombie. PhantomJS is no longer maintained. Then you can navigate to the page and find buttons using css selectors, which you can then trigger click events on.

https://phantomjs.org/

http://zombie.js.org/